# Writing a simple script for Chrome involving checking for text on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to first check for the presence of a certain text content ("No Match Found") on the web page.
If the text exists, I want to refresh the page, wait for exactly 3 seconds, then repeat the same check.
If the text DOES NOT exist, I simply want to end the loop and display an alert.

This is what I have so far:

```
var x = "No Match Found"

if (document.body.textContent.includes(x)) {
   location.reload()
   setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("btn-continue").click()
      alert("BUTTON WAS CLICKED")
   }, 3000)
}
```

Edited code a bit.

The problem now seems to be that after location.reload(), the script is no longer applying to the refreshed page. I'm unable to see even an alert popup  or console.log after the refresh happens.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what your question is.  You've given us a description, but no information about the **problem**

Comment: Edited to clarify my question. My apologies.

Comment: After `location.reload()` you effectively leave the page and the current script. No expression _after_ that method call will ever be executed. If you want things to be done by a JavaScript function then these need to happen _before_ a `location.reload()` call.

Comment: The refreshing of the page is crucial to what I'm trying to accomplish. If it causes me to leave the script, then this poses quite the problem. How do I start a function upon initial page load? I'm going to change around my code so that location.reload() is at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you could do it:

```js
const d=new Date(), x="No"+" Match Found.", 
 div=document.querySelector("div");
div.textContent=d.toLocaleString()+" - "+(d.getSeconds()%5?x:"Got it!")

// Wait a little while before checking:
setTimeout(()=>{
 if(document.body.textContent.includes(x))
  location.reload();
 else
  console.log("loop ended.");
},995);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You should not use a `while` loop for waiting, as this will completely block your browser (will make it unresponsive). Use `setTimeout()` instead. In the callback function of `setTimeout` I check for the existence of the search string and conditionally reload the page.

In my example I insert the search text into the first div on the page if the current time has a seconds value that is divisible by 5. In this case the `.includes()` method will find the search text in the target div and  my reloading cycle is stopped. I shortened the waiting time from 3 seconds to slightly under 1 second in order to get a quicker response.

In my snippet I composed the search string `x` of two parts. I did this so it wouldn't be found within my `<script>` element itself which - at least in this SO snippet - is within the `<body>` tag.

Comment: I tried this, I'm able to make sense of the code, however it doesn't accomplish what I want.